# Mod operator to scan through table entries

Tags: matlab, modulo

Is there any built-in Matlab function, let's call it **modd**, that works like the **mod** function but returns x for **modd**(x,x) (unlike **mod**(x,x) which returns 0).

Comment: The usual idiom is `mod(x-1,y)+1`